# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

Tags: php, testing, laravel-5, testcase

I have this error

> BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::attach()

for this in the test case

```
 $this->client->users()->attach($this->user->id);
```

how to fix this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: $this->client->users()->attach($this->user->id);

Comment: here is clientModel have this    ... public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }

Comment: `attach()` is only available on `BelongsToMany` relationships. What's your goal?